# Entity Framework - Bind Combobox to Normalised Table Field

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, data-binding

I am currently trying to bind an entity to a form however I want to have DataConfidenceLevel (see below) bound to a combobox with ConfidenceDescription as the display member.  What is the correct way to populate the combobox?

(I am currently using WPF but a Winforms answer is acceptable)

Thanks

[Entity Designer http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/374/entity.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/374/entity.png)

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit/change this relationship also.. or just display the firendly name?

Comment: just display the friendly name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I was expecting.

```
    comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", this.dataBindingSource, "DataConfidenceLevel", true));
    comboBox.DataSource = db.DataConfidenceLevel;
    comboBox.DisplayMember = "ConfidenceDescription";
    comboBox.ValueMember = "ConfidenceLevelID";
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to bind a collection to a control and have a releated entity - namely navigation property DataConfidenceLevel of type DataConfidenceLevel - as the display member?

That is usually achieved really simple by overriding ToString(),

```
public partial class DataConfidenceLevel
{
   public override String ToString()
   {
      return this.ConfidenceDescription;
   }
}
```

and than setting DisplayMember to the DataConfidenceLevel property of the entity you want to bind.

Comment: I'm tearing my hair out trying to get this to work.  I can't believe that something that should be so simple is so difficult.

I've overridden the ToString method on the DataConfidenceLevel class but what exactly do I use for the datasource for the combobox and what display/value members do I use?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote two blog entries about one approach to handling this situation - it applies to ASP.net, but it might help you out.

Here are the posts, the [first one](http://internationalized.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!43F3A7682D1564E4!1192.entry) is more of an introduction to the problem, the [second entry](http://internationalized.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!43F3A7682D1564E4!1216.entry) shows how to pin it all together.

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as "the correct way" but it's certainly an approach :)  I'd be happy to hear back if this helps you out!

Edit: After reading danbruc's answer, you can certainly override ToString on the Navigation property as he has suggested (for read only), but that's only a partial answer.

This won't work unless your LINQ query contains the "Include" statement, e.g.

```
var listOfThings = (from t in db.Thingy
                    .Include("DataConfidenceLevel")
                    select t).ToList();
```

Omitting the .Include() means that nothing will get bound to the column.

Comment: I am not a ASP developer, but your way of displaying releated entities in data bound controls seems way to complex. I will lay odds on ASP handling data bound entities with overwritten ToString() method the same way as WinForms does.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure what you'll have to do for making changes/updating the entity

Comment: I'll try the ToString approach and see if I run into any road blocks (there's still the issue of ensuring the navigation member is loaded or not).

Comment: Your blog links are no longer available

Comment: Sorry.. posts were migrated to http://sanderstechnology.com.  Should be able to search for them from the homepage - sorry.